# In Bokeh 1.4.0 `xaxis.major_label_text_align` appears broken

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I would like to align the x-axis tick labels to one side of the ticks or the other to make it less confusing which day the data interval corresponds to. Centering the date on midnight doesn't look right. `xaxis.major_label_text_align` appears to do nothing. It is supposed to take `right`, `left`, and `center` as options. Am I using it correctly? I cannot find any working examples. Is it not yet implemented? Using it does not give a warning. Are there any work-arounds to get the date printed after the tick that represents midnight? FYI: I can't get the tick labels to align for non-datetime labels either.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
import datetime
import random

DTF =  DatetimeTickFormatter()
DTF.days = ["%A"]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=200)

p.xaxis.formatter = DTF
p.xaxis.major_label_text_align='left' # <== THIS APPEARS TO DO NOTHING

base = datetime.datetime.today()
x = [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(10)]
#x = [1000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 8000] # <-- same issue with non-datetime
y = [random.randint(0,10) for i in range(10)]

p.line(x, y)

output_notebook()
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW my "theme builder" [app](http://bokehthemebuilder.herokuapp.com) seems to support the fact that the major_label_text_align attribute doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

That property is *technically* used, in the sense that all the plumbing is in place, and the HTML canvas drawing context configured with the value you specify. But in a practical sense, that does not translate to anything useful, because of the way Bokeh draws text. That alignment is only with respect to the low-level drawing box specified for the text on the canvas, and Bokeh always specifies a tight bounding box (meaning all text is always already simultaneously right, left, and center aligned in this specific sense—which is why changing the value has no apparent effect).

I'd suggest that you open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss this. (Though the resolution might just be "get rid of it".)

As an immediate-term workaround, you might try specifying the *angle* for the tick label. I am fairly certain you can rotate to something that is visually indistinguishable from horizontal, but anchored on an end.